# CSS position sticky not works

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

On http://www.sberbankcz.cz/en/Individuals/Accounts/fer-konto on contact form at right column. I'm using **position: fixed** when user scrolling down.

If I use **position: sticky**, it now works.

Any ideas?

Comment: be-careful with sticky it is partially supported (no IE) have a look here http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: I know. Position sticky will be main solution for Safari.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334713/position-sticky-is-not-working-with-top-property/54691099?noredirect=1#comment96169651_54691099

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file

```
#fancybox-wrap{
position: fixed;
top: 10% !important;
}
```