# position: sticky is not working with top property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Position: sticky with bottom:10px on div with class sidebar is working as expected but with property top:10px is not working as expected?

With position: sticky with bottom: 10px on div with class sidebar, when we scroll down the div stick to view port with a bottom edge above 10px to the view port.

Similarly with position: sticky with top:10px on div with class sidebar, as we scroll up the div should stick to top with the top edge of div 10px below the viewport.

But it is not working this way, what is the problem?

code: https://jsfiddle.net/c7vxwc7g/

```css
.container{
      /*width: 1654px;*/
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .sidebar{
     position: sticky;
     bottom: 10px;
      width: 400px;
      margin: 5px;
      background-color: teal;
      height: 1000px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .mainpage{
      width: 1130px;
      margin: 5px;
      margin-left: 0px; 
      background-color: steelblue;
      height: 6000px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .footer{
      height: 500px;
      width: 1654;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 10px;
      background-color: purple
    }
    .test1{
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 200px;
    }
    .test2{
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="test1">test1</div>
            <div class="test2">test2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainpage">mainpage</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: it would if it was far enough to reach the 10px limits to stick in place . example at 0 https://jsfiddle.net/c7vxwc7g/1/

Comment: now position: sticky with bottom: 0px; is not working, Goal here is that both position:sticky with bottom: 0px and with top: 0px should work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c7vxwc7g/2/ you should mind that position:sticky is still experimental and some sides effect can show up ...

Comment: ok, I am trying to make sidebar like Flipkart's sidebar (where filter and money range is present), it appears that it is positioned sticky?

Comment: I do not know what it is, do they use inline-block for the layout ?

Comment: could you suggest that how to make that?

Comment: yes! because div is block level and if we don't use inline-block it will flow below the other div! but not 100% sure.

Comment: well seen !  I would use flex , here a simple template (cloned , scroll down for both top&bottom) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mMJmRB

Comment: yeah, it's nice, let me describe the main problem: - Suppose you have a sidebar and main page just like in the template, and length of the main page is much larger than the side bar and side bar is longer than the view port. now suppose you are scrolling down the page and side bar is positioned sticky with bottom 10px,

Comment: so as you scroll down both the main page and side bar will scroll down and side bar will stick to the bottom to the page. now suppose you want to see the top of side bar but as it is positioned sticky with bottom:10px; you have to scroll all the way to up to see the top of the side bar. but I want that when you scrolled down and let say you are in the middle of the page and side bar is positioned sticky and with bottom 10px,   you should see the top of the side bar with small scroll to the top for that,

Comment: I guess as soon as user scroll up we should change the position to sticky with top 10px, instead of bottom 10px, using javascript!

Comment: sticky works once one or more value are reached untill it is pushed by other content coming at screen. the choice is that you choose either to stick it at top or at bottom( opposite values), both cannot be done unless they can match at the same time :)  You can mix a vertical and a horizontal value. What you want to do requires javascript indeed, you may drop position for the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the parent of the sticky element (the sidebar) had a smaller height than the content => the sticky element wasn't going down more than the sidebar's height.

The solution: I made the sidebar's height equal to the content's height (using display flex on the content's and sidebar's wrapper).

HTML:

```
<div clas="container">
    <div class="content">This initially has a bigger height than sidebar.</div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sticky"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { dislay: flex; } // By using this I make the sidebar the same height as the content
.sticky { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but please include your code too. with the css example your answer will be more helpful for other people.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please let me know if this is the solution you were looking for.